# Deep understanding of volatile in Java

Tags: java, volatile, lock-free, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

Does Java allows output `1, 0`? I've tested it very intensively and I cannot get that output. I get only `1, 1` or `0, 0` or `0, 1`.

```
public class Main {
    private int x;
    private volatile int g;

    // Executed by thread #1
    public void actor1(){
       x = 1;
       g = 1;
    }

    // Executed by thread #2
    public void actor2(){
       put_on_screen_without_sync(g);
       put_on_screen_without_sync(x);
    }
}
```

Why?

On my eye it is possible to get `1, 0`. My reasoning.
`g` is volatile so it causes that memory order will be ensured. So, it looks like:

```
actor1:

(1) store(x, 1)
(2) store(g, 1)
(3) memory_barrier // on x86
```

and, I see the following situation:
reorder `store(g, 1)` before `store(x,1)` (memory_barrier is **after** (2)).
Now, run thread #2. So, `g = 1, x = 0`. Now, we have expected output.
What is incorrect in my reasoning?

Comment: `println` is a synchronized method - so whatever you're testing is going to benefit from that additional synchronization. You could probably remove the volatile keyword and get the same result (depending on your CPU etc.)...

Comment: How could it ever output `1, 0`? The fields are initialized to `0`, then at some time later assigned `1`.

Comment: I've edited to avoid a confusion.

Comment: And no, 1,0 is not a legal output (regardless of the unwanted synchronization).

Comment: @assylias, why?

Comment: `volatile` is not specified in terms of memory barriers. If you want a deep understanding of `volatile` and Java thread synchronization in general, read the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

Comment: @Gilgamesz "reorder `store(g, 1)` before `store(x,1)`" is not a valid optimisation (it would not comply with the volatile semantics).

Comment: @markspace I agree with "Memory visibility is not guaranteed for x until you write g" (hence you could see x=0 in actor2 even if x=1 has been executed). But once g is read in actor2, the JMM guarantees that you will see x=1.

Comment: @Gilgamesz what may be confusing you is that the barrier ***is*** the volatile store/load, and not a separate operation.

Comment: @markspace [it isn't legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078088/1059372)

Comment: OK re-reading this, for the precise case given, it's not legal to see `1,0`  However it's really only for this exact sort of case and also making some assumptions about what is being asked here.  It could be in other very similar situations that it's legal, even expected, to see something like `1,0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any actions before a volatile write happen before (HB) any subsequent volatile read of the same variable. In your case, the write to `x` happens before the write to `g` (due to program order).

So there are only three possibilities:

- actor2 runs first and x and g are 0 - output is 0,0
- actor1 runs first and x and g are 1 because of the happens before relationship HB - output is 1,1
- the methods run concurrently and only `x=1` is executed (not `g=1`) and the output could be either 0,1 or 0,0 (no volatile write so no guarantee)

Comment: you said "Any actions before a volatile write happen before any subsequent volatile read of the same variable." I don't understand you. After all, `x` is not the same variable as `g`.

Comment: `x=1` is an action that (due to program order) happens before `g=1` which is a volatile write. `put_on_screen_without_sync(g);` is a volatile read. So any read of `x` after that statement will benefit from the volatile synchronization and will return 1.

Comment: This is a fundamental guarantee of the Java memory model. See chapter 17 of the jls for more details.

Comment: @Gilgamesz It means exactly that: any non-volatile writes that happened before the volatile write will be visible after a volatile read.

Comment: @assylias, could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151763/analyzing-of-x86-output-generated-by-jit-in-the-context-of-volatile?

Comment: it seems to me that you deduce that happens-before is an effect of program order (which is correct) and later (again, correctly) invoke that rule with `volatile`, as far as I can see you are correct, it's just that this misses the proper JLS explanation, imho. I [added it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078088/1059372) as an addendum.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.  According to the JMM, anything that was visible to thread 1 when it writes to a volatile field becomes visible to thread 2 when it reads that field.

There is another example similar to yours [provided here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile):

```
class VolatileExample {
  int x = 0;
  volatile boolean v = false;
  public void writer() {
    x = 42;
    v = true;
  }

  public void reader() {
    if (v == true) {
      //uses x - guaranteed to see 42.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will never see `1, 0`, but properly explaining this is not going to be easy, spec wise. First let's get some obvious things out of the door. The specification [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in **program order**, then hb(x, y).

This means that on the *writing* thread side, `hb(x, g)` and on the *reading* side `hb(g, x)`. But this is only so, if you would have to reason about each thread [*individually*, as the chapter about `Program order` says:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3):

> Among all the **inter-thread** actions performed by each thread t...

So if you imagine running each thread at a time, then `happens-before` would be correct for each of them, individually. But you don't. Your actors (I am sure you use `jcstress` there) run concurrently. So relying on "program order" for reasoning is not enough (neither it is correct).

You need to somehow synchronize these two actions now - the *reading* and the *writing*. And here is [how the specification says it can be done](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> A write to a volatile variable **synchronizes-with** all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

And [later](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) says:

> If an action x **synchronizes-with** a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

If you put all of these together now:

```
          (hb)              (hb)             (hb)
write(x) ------> write(g) -------> read(g) -------> read(x)
```

This is also called to "transitively" close `program order` and `synchronizes-with order`. Since there is `hb` on every step, seeing `1, 0` (a racy read), is impossible according to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

No, and in fact this property of `volatile` is used in classes like `ConcurrentHashMap` to implement a lock-free happy path, roughly like this:

```
volatile int locked = 0;
...
void mutate() {
    if (Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(locked,0,1)) { 
    /*this isn't exactly how you call this method, but the point stands: 
      if we read 0, we atomically replace it with 1 and continue on the happy 
      path */
       //we are happy
       //so we mutate the structure and then
       locked = 0;           
    } else {
       //contended lock, we aren't happy
    }
}
```

Since writes before a volatile write can't be reordered after the volatile write, and reads after volatile read can't be reordered before the volatile read, code like this indeed works as a "lockless locking".