# Analyzing of x86 output generated by JIT in the context of volatile

Tags: java, jvm, volatile, memory-barriers

I am writting this post in connection to [Deep understanding of volatile in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133832/deep-understanding-of-volatile-in-java)

```
public class Main {
    private int x;
    private volatile int g;


    public void actor1(){
       x = 1;
       g = 1;
    }


    public void actor2(){
       put_on_screen_without_sync(g);
       put_on_screen_without_sync(x);
    }
}
```

Now, I am analyzing what JIT generated for above piece of code. From our discussion in my previous post we know that output `1, 0` is impossible because:

---

write to volatile `v` causes that every action `a` preceeding `v` causes that `a` will be visible (will be flushed to memory) before `v` will be visible.

---

```
   .................(I removed not important body of method).....

  0x00007f42307d9d5e: c7460c01000000     (1) mov       dword ptr [rsi+0ch],1h
                                                ;*putfield x
                                                ; - package.Main::actor1@2 (line 14)

  0x00007f42307d9d65: bf01000000          (2) mov       edi,1h
  0x00007f42307d9d6a: 897e10              (3) mov       dword ptr [rsi+10h],edi
  0x00007f42307d9d6d: f083042400          (4) lock add  dword ptr [rsp],0h
                                                ;*putfield g
                                                ; - package.Main::actor1@7 (line 15)

  0x00007f42307d9d72: 4883c430            add       rsp,30h
  0x00007f42307d9d76: 5d                  pop       rbp
  0x00007f42307d9d77: 850583535116        test      dword ptr [7f4246cef100h],eax
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007f42307d9d7d: c3                  ret
```

Do I understand correctly that it works because x86 cannot make `StoreStore` reordering? If it could it would require additional memory barrier, yes?

---

EDITED AFTER EXCELLENT @Eugene's answer:

> ```
>  int tmp = i; // volatile load
>  // [LoadStore]
>  // [LoadLoad]
> ```

Here, I see what do you mean- it is clear: `every action below (after)` volatile read (`int tmp = i`) doesn't be reordered.

> ```
>  // [StoreLoad] -- this one
>  int tmp = i; // volatile load
>  // [LoadStore]
>  // [LoadLoad]
> ```

Here, you put one more barrier. It ensures us that no action will be reordered with `int tmp = i`. But, why it is important? Why I have doubts? From what I know `volatile load` guarantees:

Every action **after** volatile load won't be reordered before volatile load is visible.

I see you write:

> There needs to be a sequential consistency

But, I cannot see why sequential consistency is required.

Comment: What `a`? What `v`? Did you mean `x` and `g`?

Comment: Now, `a` is any action above `v`- for example it is an action: `x = 1`. `v` is a store: `g = 1`

Comment: The JMM wasn't made for x86 or any other specific architecture and doesn't reason in terms of loadload or storestore. It is the responsibility of a JVM to implement the JMM with the instructions available on each architecture.

Comment: @assylias, I know it. I'm trying to investigate why memory barrier is placed **after** `g = 1`. It seems to be errorneous but it isn't in fact. I just try to understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things, first `will be flushed to memory` - that's pretty erroneous. It's almost never a flush to main memory - it usually drains the StoreBuffer to `L1` and it's up to the cache coherency protocol to sync the data between all caches, *but* if it's easier for you to understand this concept in these terms, it's fine - just know that is slightly different and faster.

It's a good question of why the `[StoreLoad]` is there indeed, maybe this will clear up things a bit. `volatile` is indeed all about fences and here is an example of what barriers would be inserted in case of some volatile operations. For example we have a `volatile load`:

```
  // i is some shared volatile field
  int tmp = i; // volatile load of "i"
  // [LoadLoad|LoadStore]
```

Notice the two barriers here `LoadStore` and  `LoadLoad`; in plain english it means that any `Load` and `Store` that come after a `volatile load/read`  can not "move up" the barrier, they can not be re-ordered "above" that volatile load.

And here is the example for `volatile store`.

```
 // "i" is a shared volatile variable
 // [StoreStore|LoadStore]
 i = tmp; // volatile store
```

It means that any `Load` and `Store` can not go "below" the load store itself.

This basically builds the happens-before relationship, `volatile load` being the *acquiring load* and `volatile store` being the *releasing store* (this also has to do with how `Store` and `Load` cpu buffers are implemented, but it's pretty much out of the scope of the question).

If you think about it, it makes perfect sense about things that we know about `volatile` in general; it says that once a volatile store *has been observed* by a volatile load, everything prior to a `volatile store` will be observed also and this is on-par with memory barriers. It makes sense now that when a volatile store takes place, everything above it can not go beyond it, and once a volatile load happens, everything below it can not go above it, otherwise this happens-before would be broken.

*But* that's not it, there's more. There needs to be *sequential consistency*, that is why any sane implementation will guarantee that volatiles themselves are not re-ordered, thus two more fences are inserted:

```
 // any store of some other volatile
 // can not be reordered with this volatile load
 // [StoreLoad] -- this one
 int tmp = i; // volatile load of a shared variable "i"
 // [LoadStore|LoadLoad]
```

And one more here:

```
// [StoreStore|LoadStore]
i = tmp; // volatile store
// [StoreLoad] -- and this one
```

Now, it turns out that on `x86` 3 out of 4 memory barriers are free - since it is a `strong memory model`. The only one that needs to be implemented is `StoreLoad`. On other CPU's, like `ARM` for example, `lwsycn` is one instruction used - but I don't know much about them.

*Usually* an `mfence` is a good option for `StoreLoad` on `x86`, but the same thing is guaranteed via `lock add` (AFAIK in a cheaper way), that is why you see it there. Basically that *is* the `StoreLoad` barrier. And yes - you are right in your last sentence, for a weaker memory model - the `StoreStore` barrier would be required. On a side-note that is what is used when you safely publish a reference via `final` fields inside a constructor. Upon exiting the constructor there are two fences inserted: `LoadStore` and `StoreStore`.

Take all this with a grain of salt - a JVM is free to ignore these as long as it does not break any rules: Aleksey Shipilev has a great talk about this.

---

**EDIT**

Suppose you have this case :

```
[StoreStore|LoadStore]
int x = 4; // volatile store of a shared "x" variable

int y = 3; // non-volatile store of shared variable "y"

int z = x; // volatile load
[LoadLoad|LoadStore]
```

Basically there is no barrier that would prevent the `volatile store` to be re-ordered with the `volatile load` (i.e.: the volatile load would be performed *first*) and that would cause problems obviously; sequential consistency thus being violated.

You are sort of missing the point here btw (if I am not mistaken) via `Every action after volatile load won't be reordered before volatile load is visible`. Re-ordering is not possible *with the volatile itself* - other operations are free to be re-ordered. Let me give you an example:

```
 int tmp = i; // volatile load of a shared variable "i"
 // [LoadStore|LoadLoad]

 int x = 3; // plain store
 int y = 4; // plain store
```

The last two operations `x = 3` and `y = 4` are absolutely free to be re-ordered, they *can't float above the volatile*, but they can be re-ordered via themselves. The above example would be perfectly legal:

```
 int tmp = i; // volatile load
 // [LoadStore|LoadLoad]

 // see how they have been inverted here...
 int y = 4; // plain store
 int x = 3; // plain store
```

Comment: thanks for your impressive answer. I edited my post and ask one detail.

Comment: I have difficulties with your notation. What’s the difference between variables you declare in the code examples and those you don’t? When you write `int tmp = i;`, is it supposed to be a “volatile load”, because `i` is suposed to be a shared, `volatile` variable while `tmp` is supposed to be a local variable (hence, not a store operation)? Then, why is `int x = 3;` a “plain load”? Either, it is a *store*, if `x` is shared, or it is just nothing, if `x` is a local variable. In either case, I don’t see why it should be impossible to move the operation before the volatile load.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the comments, found the time to correct some missing parts. As far as the last question: we can't move any stores or loads above a volatile load, because this will break happens before. A single example proving this would be enough. Let's say I have this: `x = 3; y = 4` where x is non volatile and y is volatile; in another thread I have `z = y, x = 6`; if that `x = 6` would be allowed to float above `z = y` it would mean that once I read z to be `4`, x could be `6` - but it really has to be `3`. At least this is my understanding of this.

Comment: @Eugene just think about it a second. When you execute `z = y, x = 6`, what value will `x` have? Obviously, it will be `6`, regardless of whether you move the store or not. For any other thread, there is no guaranty anyway, they may read `3`  or `6`. So moving `x = 6` before the `z = y` does not affect the program’s behavior at all.

Comment: @Holger I have no idea what to think of this, initially I wanted to comment with `z = y; if(x == 3) {do something}; x = 6`; so `x = 6` would float across the barrier,  but this would not be allowed because of sequential consistency, I tried thinking of more example where this would break, but could not. It's just... very weird that so many places actually say this has to happen. I wish I had an ARM cpu to test this right now

Comment: That’s a naive view on it. When you have code like `if(x == 3) {do something}; x = 6;`, an optimizer still could transform it to something like `(local) tmp$x = x; x = 6; if(tmp$x == 3) {do something};`, without violating the sequential consistency. Besides that, it’s worth keeping in mind that [barriers are not Java’s memory model](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-cookbook-is-jmm). So the behavior of HotSpot, which mostly follows the JSR 133 Cookbook, is not sufficient to conclude what a conforming optimizing JVM *could* do when not being that conservative.

Comment: @Holger I know that barriers are not the JMM, even Shipilev has a great talk about this (it's in russian though); the naivety comes from lack of such deep understanding, it's not on purpose. coming to your example, are you saying that `x = 6` is now allowed to float the barrier? cause if you do that would mean that `tmp$x` could be seen as `6` and thus `if(tmp$x == 3)` would fail; if that floating across the barrier would not be allowed, that if would succeed; in *my* understanding that has to succeed.  I might need to let this one go for a short while and come to read it again...

Comment: You are assuming that it was impossible to write to `x` without subsequently reading the older value of `x`. The `tmp$x` was just one example of how this *is* possible. Of course, in this simple example, `x = 6` can not get moved before the `tmp$x = x`. But this is entirely unrelated to the volatile load of `z = y`. Even worse, in your answer, there is no load of `x`. There is only a store of `x` after the store of `y`. Though, you have written `int x = 3; // plain load`, despite you’re obviously writing to the variable. As said in my first comment, the problems start with *that* inconsistency

Comment: @Holger thank you for the patience, I think I understand what you mean; but now I don't know if such above the barriers operations would take place. This would either mean that the VM has to analyze the code to prove that those barriers are not needed or may the processor might, I don't really know. Either way, this has gotten me a lot further with my understanding thx to you