# do we need volatile when implementing singleton using double-check locking

Tags: java, singleton, synchronized, volatile

suppose we use double-check lock to implement singleton pattern:

```
    private static Singleton instance;

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Do we need to set variable "instance" as "volatile"? I hear a saying that we need it to disable reordering:

When an object is created , reordering may happen:

```
address=alloc
instance=someAddress
init(someAddress)
```

They say that if the last two steps are reordered, we need a volatile instance to disable reordering otherwise other threads may get an object that is not completely initiaized.

However since we are in a synchronized code block, do we really need volatile? Or generally, can I say that synchronized block can guarantee that a shared variable is transparent to other threads and there is no reordering even if it is not volatiled variable?

Comment: Where is the source for such information?

Comment: Just a discussion from colleagues

Comment: The real question is why are we using double check locking for our singleton (instead of an `enum` or other implementation approach)?

Comment: The real question is : Do we need to set this shared instance variable as "volitile"?

Comment: This also seems to be an issue with multiple threads. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-110 *If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.

    If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).*    See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079959/explain-how-jit-reordering-works

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've tried to answer, but it is extremely verbose.

Comment: @ScaryWombat correct, but it took quite a lot of words to show that

Comment: @Eugene I see nothing in your answer about *why we are using double check locking instead of a different implementation*... so, why use your extremely verbose answer to do it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hmm. I've tagged you by accident in response to comment below yours _The real question is : Do we need to set this shared instance variable as "volatile"?_ my bad.

Answer (score 14):

Before I go into this explanation, you need to understand one optimization that compilers do (my explanation is very simplified). Suppose that somewhere in your code you have such a sequence:

```
 int x = a;
 int y = a;
```

It is perfectly valid for a compiler to re-order these into:

```
 // reverse the order
 int y = a;
 int x = a;
```

No one `writes` to `a` here, there are only two `reads` of `a`, as such this type of re-ordering is allowed.

A slightly more complicated example would be:

```
// someone, somehow sets this
int a;

public int test() {

    int x = a;

    if(x == 4) {
       int y = a;
       return y;
    }

    int z = a;
    return z;
}
```

A compiler might look at this code and notice that if this is entered `if(x == 4) { ... }`, this : `int z = a;` never happens. But, at the same time, you can think about it slightly different: if that `if statement` is entered, we do not care if `int z = a;` is executed or not, it does not change the fact that:

```
 int y = a;
 return y;
```

would still happen. As such let's make that `int z = a;` to be eager:

```
public int test() {

   int x = a;
   int z = a; // < --- this jumped in here

   if(x == 4) {
       int y = a;
       return y;
   }

   return z;
}
```

And now a compiler can further re-order:

```
// < --- these two have switched places
int z = a;
int x = a;

if(x == 4) { ... }
```

---

Armed with this knowledge, we can try to understand now what is going on.

Let's look at your example:

```
 private static Singleton instance; // non-volatile     

 public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {  // < --- read (1)
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (instance == null) { // < --- read (2)
                instance = new Singleton(); // < --- write 
            }
        }
    }
    return instance; // < --- read (3)
}
```

There are 3 reads of `instance` (also called `load`) and a single `write` to it (also called `store`). As weird at it may sound, but if `read (1)` has seen an `instance` that is not null (meaning that `if (instance == null) { ... }` is not entered), it does not mean that `read (3)` will return a non-null instance, it is perfectly valid for `read (3)` to still return `null`. This should melt your brain (it did mine a few times). Fortunately, there is a way to prove this.

A compiler might add such a small optimization to your code:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Singleton();
                // < --- we added this
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

It inserted a `return instance`, semantically this does not change the logic of the code in any way.

Then, there is a [certain optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) that compilers do that will help us here. I am not going to dive into the details, but it introduces some local fields (the benefit is in that link) to do all the reads and writes (stores and loads).

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    Singleton local1 = instance;   // < --- read (1)
    if (local1 == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            Singleton local2 = instance; // < --- read (2)
            if (local2 == null) {
                Singleton local3 = new Singleton();
                instance = local3; // < --- write (1)
                return local3;
            }
        }
    }

    Singleton local4 = instance; // < --- read (3)
    return local4;
}
```

Now a compiler might look at this and see that: if `if (local2 == null) { ... }` is entered, `Singleton local4 = instance;` never happens (or as said in the example I started this answer with: it does not really matter if `Singleton local4 = instance;` happens at all). But in order to enter `if (local2 == null) {...}`, we need to enter this `if (local1 == null) { ... }` first. And now let's reason about this as a whole:

```
if (local1 == null) { ... } NOT ENTERED => NEED to do : Singleton local4 = instance

if (local1 == null) { ... } ENTERED && if (local2 == null) { ... } NOT ENTERED 
=> MUST DO : Singleton local4 = instance. 

if (local1 == null) { ... } ENTERED && if (local2 == null) { ... } ENTERED
=> CAN DO : Singleton local4 = instance.  (remember it does not matter if I do it or not)
```

You can see that in all the cases, there is no harm in doing that :  `Singleton local4 = instance` **before any if checks**.

After all this madness, your code could become:

```
 public static Singleton getInstance() {

    Singleton local4 = instance; // < --- read (3)
    Singleton local1 = instance;   // < --- read (1)

    if (local1 == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            Singleton local2 = instance; // < --- read (2)
            if (local2 == null) {
                Singleton local3 = new Singleton();
                instance = local3; // < --- write (1)
                return local3;
            }
        }
    }

    return local4;
}
```

There are two independent reads of `instance` here:

```
Singleton local4 = instance; // < --- read (3)
Singleton local1 = instance;   // < --- read (1)

if(local1 == null) {
   ....
}

return local4;
```

You read `instance` into `local4` (let's suppose a `null`), then you read `instance` into `local1` (let's assume that some thread already changed this into a non-null) and ... your `getInstance` will return a `null`, not a `Singleton`. q.e.d.

---

Conclusion: these optimizations are *only* possible when `private static Singleton instance;` is `non-volatile`, otherwise much of the optimization are prohibited and nothing like this would be even possible. So, yes, using `volatile` is a MUST for this pattern to work correctly.

Comment: What is scarier, is if you see a not fully constructed object. After all, the compiler might reorder the stores in the constructor with the store to `instance` if it is not volatile.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn  right, you are talking about _safe publication_ and for that to work correctly with `volatile`, both reader and writer have to work together, as a pair, on the same `volatile`.

Comment: While the problem explained in this answer can be solved by declaring the field `volatile`, it could also be solved by reading the field once and storing it into a local variable instead of reading the field twice. So, the real reason why the field should be volatile (unless the singleton is a truly immutable object), has not been explained yet. And, whenever someone feels the need to discuss the double-checked locking, the pointlessness of it should be mentioned, as the class initialization provides all thread safe lazy initialization *for free*.

Comment: @Holger agreed. I did this only as an exercise and out of pure interest.

Comment: @Holger can you please elaborate on the last sentence? How is DCL useless even with volatile?

Comment: @Vaibhav as said “*the class initialization provides all thread safe lazy initialization for free*”. So just declare the field as `private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();` and it will be initialized on the class’s first use, i.e. when `getInstance()` is invoked the first time. The method itself is as simple as `public static Singleton getInstance() { return instance; }` then. It’s lazy, it’s thread safe, and it’s even more efficient than any DCL approach, as after the class has been initialized, the JVM is free to read the field without any locking.

Comment: @Holger If it is being initialized at the time of class loading i am not sure how can it be called lazy

Comment: It’s not initialized when the class is loaded. Class loading is a different thing than class initialization. The time of initialization [is precisely specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). In this specific case, it’s *immediately before the static method `getInstance()` is invoked for the first time*. Which is as lazy as the double checked locking tries to achieve. If you invoke it three days after the application start, the initialization will happen three days after start; if don’t invoke `getInstance()`, the initialization will never happen.

Comment: @Holger ah understood. All this time the answer was Occam's razor.